# confusing output when iterate golang unbuffered channel

Tags: go, slice, channel

I meet a confusing output when iterate a golang unbuffered channel. 
The channel is defined as `chan []int`. 
Then I push two slice to the channel, [0 1] and [2 3]. But when I fetch element from the channel, I got [2 3] and [2 3]. why this happens?

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "sync"

func producer(jobs chan []int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()

    a := make([]int, 2)
    index := 0
    for i := 0; i < 4; i++ {
        a[index] = i
        index++
        if index == 2 {
            index = 0
            fmt.Printf("a: %+v\n", a)
            jobs <- a
        }    
    }

    close(jobs)
}

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)
    jobs := make(chan []int, 2)
    go producer(jobs, &wg)
    for job := range jobs {
        fmt.Printf("job: %+v\n", job)
    }

    wg.Wait()
}
```

expected output:

```
a: [0 1]
a: [2 3]
job: [0 1]
job: [2 3]
```

actual output:

```
a: [0 1]
a: [2 3]
job: [2 3]
job: [2 3]
```

Comment: add `a = make([]int, 2)` after `jobs <- a`

Comment: compile error for this code , I think need a modification in line 29 ( from `go producer(ch, &wg)`to `go producer(jobs, &wg)`

Answer (score 2):

A slice contains a pointer to the backing array. When you send the slice through channel, you're sending a reference to that backing array, so on the receiving end even when you read the slice multiple times, you actually refer to the same shared backing array.

You can create a new slice for each iteration and send that. Each slice will have a separate backing array and will work as you expect.

Answer (score -1):

Slightly modified your program for better reading.

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "sync"

func producer(jobs chan []int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()

    a := make([]int, 2)
    a[0] = 1
    a[1] = 2
            jobs <- a   //We are passing memory location of slice ( is nature of slice ), so the values changing next line will affect here too
    a[0] = 2
    a[1] = 3
           jobs <- a  
    

    close(jobs)
}

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)
    jobs := make(chan []int, 2)
    go producer(jobs, &wg)
    for job := range jobs {
        fmt.Printf("job: %+v\n", job)
    }

    wg.Wait()
}
```

Same program I tried with Array , then we will get the result you are expecting , see below code

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "sync"

func producer(jobs chan [2]int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()

   var a[2]int
    a[0] = 1
    a[1] = 2
            jobs <- a   
    a[0] = 2
    a[1] = 3
           jobs <- a  
    

    close(jobs)
}

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)
    jobs := make(chan [2]int)
    go producer(jobs, &wg)
    for job := range jobs {
        fmt.Printf("job: %+v\n", job)
    }

    wg.Wait()
}
```

[Playground Link - Program using Slice](https://play.golang.org/p/nYBGLHDbsgO)

[Playground Link - Program using Array](https://play.golang.org/p/KwZhEGJ7GBl)

**The ground rule is Slices are passed by reference**